# How to have a link of js array and img src in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React component that maps data from a .js file, containing objects in the array. How can I link my title and images from within this function to access respective pages?

In this file, I am getting errors for every [x] used for linking img src to the info.js file
Is there a different way to link an img from a js array?

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Card from "./Card";
import Btt from "./BackToTop";
import info from "../info";

function Bolt() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>
            <h1 className="projHead">Bolt</h1>
            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].src} alt="" className="banner"></img> 
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className="text1">
                <h3>Mind Map</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic1} alt="" className="isoimg"></img></div>

            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic2} alt="" className="isoimg"></img></div>

            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic3} alt="" className="isoimg"></img></div>

            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic4} alt="" className="isoimg"></img></div>

            <div className="text1">
                <h3>Screen Layouts</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic5} alt="" className="isoimg"></img></div>

            <div className="text1">
                <h3>Mockups</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-img-top"><img src={info.[1].pic6} alt="" className="smallisoimg"></img></div>

            <Btt />   
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Bolt;
```

this is the JS file for content

```
const info = [
    {
        id:    1,
        title: "AR mirror",
        about: "Smart Exercise Mirror is an IOT product. It helps the user to have a gym-like experience at their home with the help of AR and image recognition technology. ",
        src:   "images/AR_Mirror/AR_mirror.png",
        tag1: "UX & Product design",
        link: "/ARmirror",
        targ: "_self",
        pic1: "images/AR_Mirror/ar1.jpg",
        pic2: "images/AR_Mirror/ar2.png",
        pic3: "images/AR_Mirror/ar3.png",
        pic4: "images/AR_Mirror/ar4.png",
        pic5: "images/AR_Mirror/ar5.gif",
        pic6: "images/AR_Mirror/ar6.png",
        vid: "images/AR_Mirror/AR_mirror.MOV",
    },

    {
        id:    2,
        title: "Bolt",
        about: "Bolt is an app for electric bikes which allows user to monitor the bike from remote distance and functions as a control panel.",
        src:   "images/Bolt/Bolt.jpg",
        tag1: "UX design",
        link: "/Bolt",
        targ: "_self",
        pic1: "images/Bolt/bs1.png",
        pic2: "images/Bolt/bs2.png",
        pic3: "images/Bolt/bs3.png",
        pic4: "images/Bolt/bs4.png",
        pic5: "images/Bolt/bs5.png",
        pic6: "images/Bolt/bs6.gif",
    }
    
];

export default info;
```

Comment: can you send the errors ?

Comment: What are the specific errors, or issues, you are having with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, this syntax (`info.[1]`) is wrong. That's why you have errors.
You should change it to `info[1]`. Thats orthodox way of accessing array elements by their indices.

Other than this, you should better use `map` or `foreach` iterating over array.

Comment: Thanks, @marmeladze
This solution works. Will try the map thing as well

Answer (score 0):

In that case just replace

```
info.[1].pic1
```

to

```
info?.[1]?.pic1
```

If you doing it static then its fine.
But in future if you are using more data it will be better to use For-loop or Map because it's better way to use array data